# Draw an image on a Canvas from an Object property

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I want to draw an image on the canvas at each iteration, an image coming from an object.
Either I get "not the format HTML..." in the console, or nothing and it blocks the loop.

Is there a way to draw an image on a canvas without putting it first on the index.html, or without loading from an URL?

I tried the two standard solutions and they didn't work.

I didn't find a similar problem using an object property containing the image, to draw it on a canvas.

```
function Board(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.chartBoard = [];

    // Création du plateau logique
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        const row = [];
        this.chartBoard.push(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            const col = {};
            row.push(col);
        }
    }
}
let board = new Board(10, 10);
console.log(board);

// CONTEXT OF THE CANVAS
const ctx = $('#board').get(0).getContext('2d');

Board.prototype.drawBoard = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.strokeRect(j * 64, i * 64, 64, 64);
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
};

board.drawBoard();



Board.prototype.test = test;

function test() {
    console.log(this);
}


// OBJECT TO DRAW
function Obstacle(name, sprite) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sprite = sprite;
}

const lava = new Obstacle("Lave", "assets/lave.png");
const lava1 = new Obstacle("Lave1", "assets/lave.png");
const lava2 = new Obstacle("Lave2", "assets/lave.png");
const lava3 = new Obstacle("Lave3", "assets/lave.png");
const lava4 = new Obstacle("Lave4", "assets/lave.png");
const lava5 = new Obstacle("Lave5", "assets/lave.png");
const lava6 = new Obstacle("Lave6", "assets/lave.png");
const lava7 = new Obstacle("Lave7", "assets/lave.png");
const lava8 = new Obstacle("Lave8", "assets/lave.png");
const lava9 = new Obstacle("Lave9", "assets/lave.png");
const lavaArray = [lava, lava1, lava2, lava3, lava4, lava5, lava6, lava7, lava8, lava9];


// FUNCTION TO DRAW

Board.prototype.setPiece = function (piece) {

    let randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * board.width);
    let randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * board.height);

    let drawX = randomX * 64;
    let drawY = randomY * 64;


    if (randomX >= this.width || randomY >= this.height) {
        throw new Error('Pièce hors limite');
    }

    if (piece instanceof Obstacle) {

        if (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Obstacle)) {
            this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] = piece;

            // CODE TO DRAW, BUG DOESN'T WORK
            ctx.fillRect(drawX, drawY,64,64);
            let image = Obstacle.sprite;
            ctx.drawImage = (image, drawX, drawY);
        }
    } 

    } else {
        throw new Error('Pièce non valide');
    }
};

Board.prototype.setObstacles = function () {
    for (let lava of lavaArray) {

        const obstacle = board.setPiece(lava);
    }
};
board.setObstacles();
```

**Actual:** No image is drawn. And if I try fillRect, it works well. So the loop works.

**Expected:** Be able to draw an image on a canvas from an object property.

Comment: @gman - you should write that as answer. That'll fix it.

Comment: @gman With your modification I get:
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Comment: That's because Obstacle.sprite is not an image - it is a string.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Is there a way to store an image as an object property, so the drawImage function loads it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

The code you have commented

```
ctx.drawImage = (image, drawX, drawY);
```

should be this

```
ctx.drawImage(image, drawX, drawY);
```

Looking a little broader you have this

```
let image = Obstacle.sprite;
ctx.drawImage(image, drawX, drawY);  // assume this was fixed
```

But `Obstacle` is a class, not an instance of that class. You want

```
let image = piece.sprite;
ctx.drawImage(image, drawX, drawY);
```

But that leads the next issue. looking at the rest of the code `piece.sprite` is a string not an image. See this code.

```
// OBJECT TO DRAW
function Obstacle(name, sprite) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sprite = sprite;
}

const lava = new Obstacle("Lave", "assets/lave.png");
```

There are a several ways you can draw images to a canvas. If they come from a file you do have to wait for them to download. Otherwise you can generate them from another canvas. You can also use `createImageData` and `putImageData` as another way to make images.

Let's change the code to load a bunch of images and then start

I moved all the class code to the top and the start up code to the bottom.

There were a few places inside `Board` methods where the global variable `board` was used instead of `this` so I fixed those.

Here`s a function that loads an image and returns a Promise

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => { resolve(img); };
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';  // REMOVE IF SAME DOMAIN!
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

You could use that to load one image like this

```
loadImage(urlOfImage).then(function(img) {
  // use the loaded img
});
```

I used that function to write this function that takes an object of names to urls and returns an object of names to loaded images.

```
function loadImages(images) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const loadedImages = {};
    const imagePromises = Object.entries(images).map((keyValue) => {
      const [name, url] = keyValue;
      return loadImage(url).then((img) => {
         loadedImages[name] = img;
      });
    });
    Promise.all(imagePromises).then(() => {
      resolve(loadedImages);
    });
  });
}
```

I then call that and pass the object of names to loaded images to the `start` function. Only one image is loaded at the moment but you can add more.

```
const images = {
  lave: 'https://i.imgur.com/enx5Xc8.png',
  // player: 'foo/player.png',
  // enemy: 'foo/enemny.png',
};
loadImages(images).then(start);
```

```js
// CONTEXT OF THE CANVAS
const ctx = $('#board').get(0).getContext('2d');

function Board(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.chartBoard = [];

    // Création du plateau logique
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        const row = [];
        this.chartBoard.push(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            const col = {};
            row.push(col);
        }
    }
}

Board.prototype.drawBoard = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.strokeRect(j * 64, i * 64, 64, 64);
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
};

// OBJECT TO DRAW
function Obstacle(name, sprite) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sprite = sprite;
}


// FUNCTION TO DRAW

Board.prototype.setPiece = function (piece) {

    let randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.width);
    let randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.height);

    let drawX = randomX * 64;
    let drawY = randomY * 64;


    if (randomX >= this.width || randomY >= this.height) {
        throw new Error('Pièce hors limite');
    }

    if (piece instanceof Obstacle) {

        if (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Obstacle)) {
            this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] = piece;

            // CODE TO DRAW, BUG DOESN'T WORK
            ctx.fillRect(drawX, drawY,64,64);
            let image = piece.sprite;
            ctx.drawImage(image, drawX, drawY);
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('Pièce non valide');
    }
};

Board.prototype.setObstacles = function (lavaArray) {
    for (let lava of lavaArray) {

        const obstacle = this.setPiece(lava);
    }
};

function start(images) {
  let board = new Board(10, 10);
//  console.log(board);

  const lava = new Obstacle("Lave", images.lave);
  const lava1 = new Obstacle("Lave1", images.lave);
  const lava2 = new Obstacle("Lave2", images.lave);
  const lava3 = new Obstacle("Lave3", images.lave);
  const lava4 = new Obstacle("Lave4", images.lave);
  const lava5 = new Obstacle("Lave5", images.lave);
  const lava6 = new Obstacle("Lave6", images.lave);
  const lava7 = new Obstacle("Lave7", images.lave);
  const lava8 = new Obstacle("Lave8", images.lave);
  const lava9 = new Obstacle("Lave9", images.lave);
  const lavaArray = [lava, lava1, lava2, lava3, lava4, lava5, lava6, lava7, lava8, lava9];

  board.drawBoard();


  board.setObstacles(lavaArray);
}

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => { resolve(img); };
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';  // REMOVE IF SAME DOMAIN!
    img.src = url;
  });
}

function loadImages(images) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const loadedImages = {};
    // for each name/url pair in image make a promise to load the image
    // by calling loadImage
    const imagePromises = Object.entries(images).map((keyValue) => {
      const [name, url] = keyValue;
      // load the image and when it's finished loading add the name/image
      // pair to loadedImages
      return loadImage(url).then((img) => {
         loadedImages[name] = img;
      });
    });
    // wait for all the images to load then pass the name/image object
    Promise.all(imagePromises).then(() => {
      resolve(loadedImages);
    });
  });
}

const images = {
  lave: 'https://i.imgur.com/enx5Xc8.png',
  // player: 'foo/player.png',
  // enemy: 'foo/enemny.png',
};
loadImages(images).then(start);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="board" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw there is the drawImage to create an image object.

I didn't find a way to save an image as an object property. Because if I need different images during the loop (several objects), then I can't load each one manually.

Comment: @GrégoryHuyghe - Load the images at runtime and allow the browser's local cache to deal with the "reloading" part.

Comment: @gman Great answer thanks. It works very well. I will study it to understand it clearly.